# User Activity Following

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an activity model

```
id | activity_model | activity_type | user_id | activity_id | created_at | updated_at|
1  | Article        | Created       | 1       |   25        | a time     |  a time   |
2  | Headline Story | Created       | 1       |   26        | a time     |  a time   |
```

**activity_model is a string

Now lets say my controller has (actually cleaner as the second portion is in the model):

```
@user_activity = Activity.where(user_id: 1).all
```

I would like my view to be something like this:

```
      - @user_activity.each do |activity|
        - if activity_model == "Article"
          = link_to Article.find(activity.activity_id).name, activity
        elsif activity_model == "Headline Story"
          = link_to HeadlineStory.find(activity.activity_id).name, activity
        = activity.activity_type
        = "#{time_ago_in_words(activity.created_at)} ago"
```

I am focusing on the if statement portion of the block above.

The question I have is. As I am iterating through these different model types how do I get my link_to's to be clean? I'm using find in the view, that can't be right..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through `Activity` objects and find `Article` objects at the same time you could do this in a couple of ways:

- Populate a hash table in the controller and use it in the view.
- Create a *View model* which you populate within the controller and use it to render your view.
- Create a helper function which you can use within the view.

The first and last options are the fastest to implement.